# Generate item and subitem fields from multi-lined excel sheet in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

How do I transform an excel sheet in pandas to have item and sub-item columns

**Input**

```
     |-----------------+-------+---------|
     |                 | year1 | year2   |
     | 1. item1        |       |         |
     | (1 continued)   | value | value   |
     | 1.1 sub-item    |       |         |
     | (1.1 continued) | value | value   |
     | 1.2 sub-item    | value | value   |
     | ...             |       |         |
     | 2. item2        |       |         |
     | 2.1 sub-item    | value | value   |
     | ..              |       |         |
     |                 |       |         |
```

**Desired output**

```
 |-------+--------------+-------+-------+---|
 | item1 |              | year1 | value |   |
 | item1 | sub-item 1.1 | year1 | value |   |
 | item1 | sub-item 1.2 | year1 | value |   |
 | item1 | sub-item 1.3 | year1 | value |   |
 | ...   |              |       |       |   |
 | item2 | sub-item 2.1 | year1 | value |   |
 | item2 | sub-item 2.2 | year1 | value |   |
 | ..    |              |       |       |   |
 |       |              |       |       |   |
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, can you provide some rows of examples?

Comment: Had to manually edit all the text that would overflow to two rows into a single row from the 'Head of Account' column. Have written code to take a single level of row names- values but stuck on how to create item and subitem in different output columns

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:

1. you read in the csv as a data frame
2. you use a regular expression to recognize/split the features of the first column that start with a number with a subsequent dot (first level) into a new column.
3. you use a regular expression to recognize/split the features of the new column that start with a number, a subsequent dot and a number (second level) into a new column.
4. you copy the features without a number into the second level column.
5. Now fill the missing features of the first level downwards.

Comment: Will give it a go, it does seem like it would work. Thanks!

Comment: This answer helped, I've updated my question where there are instances where the name of the item(along with sub-items) also flows over two rows @magraf